# System.Threading.Tasks error when trying to call API

Tags: vb.net, api

I am new to vb.net code. I have to call external API from vb.net. I tried the code below but it is throwing an error - getting issue as

> System.Threading.Tasks.k`1

```
Public Shared Async Function GetToken_saka() As Task(Of sakaweb)
    Dim req As New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://api.qa.se.com/token")
    '        req.Content = New FormUrlEncodedContent(New Dictionary < String, String > {
    '    {"client_id", "your client_id"},
    '    {"client_secret", "your client_secret"},
    '    {"grant_type", "client_credentials"}
    '});

    Dim dct As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    dct.Add("client_id", "your_client_id")
    dct.Add("client_secret", "your_client_secret")
    dct.Add("grant_type", "client_credentials")

    Dim htc As New HttpClient
    req.Content = New FormUrlEncodedContent(dct)
    Dim response = Await htc.SendAsync(req)
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()

    'Dim payload = JObject.Parse(Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync())
    Dim payload = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.ToString)

    Dim token = payload.Value(Of String)("access_token")
    Dim t1 As sakaweb = Nothing
    Return t1

    'Dim t1 As New Task("K")
    'Return t1
End Function
```

Comment: There's probably an inner exception...

Comment: If the `client_id` and `client_secret` are actual real values (they look it), I would edit your post to change them quickly.

Comment: Testing this code, you actually posted valid credentials, since the API returns a valid JSON and no exceptions. The commented-out code is the correct version: `dim json = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() Dim payload = JObject.Parse(json) dim token = payload("access_token").ToString()`. No idea what `sakaweb` is and you're creating a null object; your method should probably return a string (the `token` string) and change the return type as `Task(Of String)`. You need to await this method, as, e.g., `Dim accessToken = Await GetToken_saka()`